# How to make html elements flow like text

Tags: css

Given I have two (or more) elements, ーlet's use `div` but they can be `span` or anything...ー I want the second one to be appended to the first one the same way it would happen with text.

HTML:

```html
<div>First element taking space</div> <div>Second element</div>
```

What I want:

```
//<------ 1. parent width big enough -------->
First element taking space Second element

//<---- 2. bit smaller width ------>
First element taking space Second
element

//<- 3. even smaller ->
First element taking
space Second element
```

What it happens

```
//<------ 1. parent width big enough -------->
First element taking space Second element

//<---- 2. bit smaller width ------>
First element taking space          // even if there's space for the "Second" word in
Second element                      // the 1st line it starts in the next line

//<- 3. even smaller ->
First element taking      // even if there's space for the "Second element" full text
space                     // it starts in a new line
Second element
```

This is probably due to the "box" assigned to each element, behaving like this

```
╔══════════════════════╗
║╔════════════════════╗║
║║First element taking║║
║║space               ║║
║╚════════════════════╝║
║╔══════════════╗      ║
║║Second element║      ║
║╚══════════════╝      ║
╚══════════════════════╝
```

I tried playing with `display` options (`inline`, `inline-block`, `flex`), `white-space` (`wrap`, `pre-wrap`)... but can't make it work as I want.

Note: the `pre-wrap` is because I want to preserve spaces as well.

**Edit:** Added the following snippet with current code:

```css
.root {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: pink;
}

.prefix {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.text {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.colored {
  background: red;
}

.big { width: 500px; }
.small { width: 320px; }
.smaller { width: 150px; }
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="prefix">1.&gt; </div>
  <div class="text">this is some text of arbitrary width </div>
  <div class="text colored">colored text</div>
  <div class="text"> more text</div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="root small">
  <div class="prefix">2.&gt; </div>
  <div class="text">this is some text of arbitrary width </div>
  <div class="text colored">colored text</div>
  <div class="text"> more text</div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="root smaller">
  <div class="prefix">3.&gt; </div>
  <div class="text">this is some text of arbitrary width </div>
  <div class="text colored">colored text</div>
  <div class="text"> more text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't do that for block elements

Comment: @Justinas that's why I said I played as well with display options (inline/inline-block), and also tried float: left... but nothing

Comment: I think `display: contents;` does what you want.

Comment: @pistevw and I think you are right. Didn't now about that option!

Comment: No, I haven't used it myself but I've read about it. Glad it helped!

Comment: both div need to be display:inline

Comment: @pistevw the only problem with the `display: contents` solution is that it doesn't accept background (i.e. color) because it doesn't generate any box... :-/

Comment: @danikaze But can't you just wrap the divs with `display: contents;` in a parent that gets the background?

Comment: @pistevw but what if you want to apply the background to only one of the divs? i.e. only to the first element, or have the 1st and 2nd have different colors?

Comment: @danikaze Then you could wrap them each in separate parents and give the background-color to the wrapper you want.

Comment: @pistevw but what I say is that, to be able to give them bg-color you have to provide a box. At the moment you provide the box, then the lines break as the beginning... or at least that's what I'm experiencing while testing

Comment: -added snippet with some code to explain better the situation-

Comment: Ah, I understand! Sorry, I didn't think of that. I haven't used this as I said and maybe there is a better solution but maybe it's possible to wrap the content in a span, which is an inline element and then play with line-height and font-size. Just a tought though and I can't guarantee it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was very simple and stupid to the point I'm embarrassed: Just use inline elements.

Leaving it here as well in case anyone learning needs it...

```css
.root {
  background: pink;
}

.prefix {
  display: inline; /* not needed if using native inline tags such as <span> */
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.text {
  display: inline; /* not needed if using native inline tags such as <span> */
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.colored {
  display: inline; /* not needed if using native inline tags such as <span> */
  background: red;
}

.big { width: 500px; }
.small { width: 320px; }
.smaller { width: 150px; }
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="prefix">1.&gt; </div>
  <div class="text">this is some text of arbitrary width </div>
  <div class="text colored">colored text</div>
  <div class="text"> more text</div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="root small">
  <div class="prefix">2.&gt; </div>
  <div class="text">this is some text of arbitrary width </div>
  <div class="text colored">colored text</div>
  <div class="text"> more text</div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="root smaller">
  <div class="prefix">3.&gt; </div>
  <div class="text">this is some text of arbitrary width </div>
  <div class="text colored">colored text</div>
  <div class="text"> more text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if I understood you correctly but I think flexbox would solve your problem, take a look at the snippet below:

```css
    .container{
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height:100vh;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .first-box{
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: yellowgreen;
    }
    .second-box{
        width:auto;
        height:auto;
        display:flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: tomato;
    }
```

```html
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <div class="container">
    <div class="first-box">This is some text.</div>
    <div class="second-box">This is some text but in the second div which has a tomato background-color.</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: but here you are providing fixed sizes to each box... what's the point then? sorry if I wasn't clear but, if the text changes this doesn't work.

Comment: Take a look at it now, I updated it. You can set the width and height to auto and then the whole div/element will be depended by it's own content, in your case, it's text.

Comment: but the result of your snippet is not the expected in the question. they both split lines in their own boxes, don't continue the flow like regular text.

Comment: Can you please show us at least a picture of your desired output?

Comment: Glad you did it haha. Sorry for not quite catching you though

Comment: Appreciate the help :)